# Как подсчитать, сколько раз встречается то или иное значение?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как правильно подсчитать данные при помоще `'count'` или возможно другим способом данные из бд?

Есть 5 полей в таблице, в поле есть 6 вариантов значений:

```
1_day - Выходной, Рабочий, Отгул, Отпуск, Прогул, Больничный
2_day - Выходной, Рабочий, Отгул, Отпуск, Прогул, Больничный
3_day - Выходной, Рабочий, Отгул, Отпуск, Прогул, Больничный
4_day - Выходной, Рабочий, Отгул, Отпуск, Прогул, Больничный
5_day - Выходной, Рабочий, Отгул, Отпуск, Прогул, Больничный
```

Как подсчитать количество выходных дней во всех полях?
Примером:

```
1_day = Выходной
2_day = Выходной
3_day = Рабочий
4_day = Выходной
5_day = Отгул
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 отдельных полей под дни - это жуть. Должно быть 5 записей в отдельной таблице. В вашем случае поможет только что то типа

```
select sum(if(`1_day`='Выходной',1,0)+
           if(`2_day`='Выходной',1,0)+
           ...
           if(`5_day`='Выходной',1,0)
          )
   from table
  group by ... /* Если нужно */
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT day, count(*) from table group by day
```

только полей должно быть не 5, а одно

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table_name where (day) in (SELECT day
FROM table_name
group by day
having count(*)>1)
```

Запрос ищет Ваше количество дублей

Answer (score 1):

плохо группировать по строкам да и если честно я бы вынес значения `Выходной, Рабочий, Отгул, Отпуск, Прогул, Больничный` в отдельную таблицу а в основную писал бы `id`(Может же добавится любой статус Дикрет например или Командировка) или сделать ENUM поле но тут плохо добавлять значение т.к. прийдется делать это через `ALTER TABLE`. но имеем то что имеем.

Примерно так я бы сделал:
`SELECT CONUNT(day) as cnt_day FROM table GROUP BY 'day_status'`

Comment: @ДмитрийКуть привидите структуру таблицы тогда

Comment: @ДмитрийКуть группировка по cf_2379. `SELECT CONUNT(cf_2379) as cnt_day FROM table GROUP BY 'cf_2379'` при такой структуре без  особых трудностей можно сделать поле `ENUM` дать ему индекс и получить халявный прирост по производительности